# Data deduplication using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, data-cleaning

**I am trying to clean up my loaded CSV file using multiple columns values, so I can filter duplicate records out of it and hopefully drop them out, But I get and error related to date:**

**My sample data is:**

| ACTIVITY_DATE | OWNNER_ID | OWNER_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2020 | 23344 | JAMES NELSON |
| 2/1/2020 | 33445 | NIGEL THOMAS |
| 1/1/2020 | 23344 | JAMES NELSON |
| 2/1/2020 | 33445 | NIGEL THOMAS |

**My code is:**

```
inspections = inspections[inspections.duplicated(subset=['ACTIVITY_DATE','OWNER_ID'], keep=False)]
```

**My error is:**

```
KeyError: 'ACTIVITY_DATE'
```

**÷ntended output**

| ACTIVITY_DATE | OWNNER_ID | OWNER_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2020 | 23344 | JAMES NELSON |
| 2/1/2020 | 33445 | NIGEL THOMAS |

Comment: unable to reproduce.

Comment: check `print(inspections.columns)` if there are spaces (preceding or succeeding) in the name of the column

Comment: Please provide reproducing code for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your particular example, the .drop_duplicates() should be just fine?

```
In [71]: df
Out[71]:
  ACTIVITY_DATE  OWNNER_ID    OWNER_NAME
0      1/1/2020      23344  JAMES NELSON
1      2/1/2020      33445  NIGEL THOMAS
2      1/1/2020      23344  JAMES NELSON
3      2/1/2020      33445  NIGEL THOMAS

In [72]: df.drop_duplicates()
Out[72]:
  ACTIVITY_DATE  OWNNER_ID    OWNER_NAME
0      1/1/2020      23344  JAMES NELSON
1      2/1/2020      33445  NIGEL THOMAS
```

Alternatively, if you want to provide only a subset of columns to be compared, you can do it this way:

```
In [77]: df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ACTIVITY_DATE','OWNNER_ID'])
Out[77]:
  ACTIVITY_DATE  OWNNER_ID    OWNER_NAME
0      1/1/2020      23344  JAMES NELSON
1      2/1/2020      33445  NIGEL THOMAS
```